# Apply cumsum function to a variable with several conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, cumsum

I am having similar data to this one:

```
data <- data.frame (date=seq.Date(as.Date("2021-03-21"),as.Date("2021-04-21"),"day"),
                    rad= sample(1:10,32, replace = T))

> head(data)
        date rad
1 2021-03-21   1
2 2021-03-22   5
3 2021-03-23   1
4 2021-03-24   9
5 2021-03-25  10
6 2021-03-26   4
...
```

I am currently learning to twist and manipulate big datasets and stumbled upon a case where my R knowledge/googling skills are just not helping anymore.

I would like to learn two things:

1. How to assign values to a variable for a certain period. Let's say for example, I want to give a value of 42 to all elements from the rad column for the time period between 2021-04-01 and 2021-04-05.
2. More importantly (and unrelatedly to 1. ) I would like to create a code that:

- creates a new column based on the "rad" variable
- calculates the cumsum of "rad" for a certain time period (e.g. 2021-04-01 - 2021-04-05)
- Then takes the last value of the cumsum (the total sum of the cumulative summed period) and assigns it for a certain time period (e.g. 2021-04-06 - 2021-04-15)
- The new variable has the same values as the "rad" variable for rest of the dates to which no function is applied

I simply do not know how to present you the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a boolean vector to specify the rows you want to modify:

```
data <- data.frame(date=seq.Date(as.Date("2021-03-21"),as.Date("2021-04-21"),"day"),
                    rad= sample(1:10,32, replace = T))

# Specify rows to be modified
modified <- data$date>=as.Date('2021-04-01') & data$date<=as.Date('2021-04-05')
modified.after <- data$date>as.Date('2021-04-06') & data$date<=as.Date('2021-04-15')

# First question
# data$rad[modified] <- 42

# Second question
data$radnew <- data$rad
cs <- cumsum(data$rad[modified])

data$radnew[modified] <- cs
data$radnew[modified.after] <- tail(cs,1) 
data
```

Comment: Perhaps `data$date>as.Date('2021-04-06')&data$date>as.Date('2021-04-15')` should be `data$date>=as.Date('2021-04-06')&data$date<=as.Date('2021-04-15')`, with the comparison on the 2nd term reversed and the extremes included.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your first question, in `base R` you can subset `data` on the date period mentioned and assign the value `42` for that period in a new variable, say `x`:

```
data$rad[data$date >= "2021-04-01" & data$date <= "2021-04-05"] <- 42
```

You can achieve the same thing using `dplyr` thus:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(rad = ifelse(date >= "2021-04-01" & date <= "2021-04-05", 42, NA))
```

**EDIT**:

As to your second question (if I understand it correctly) you are probably best served using `dplyr` in this way:

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    new1 = ifelse(date >= "2021-04-01" & date <= "2021-04-05", 42, NA),
    cmsm = cumsum(date >= "2021-04-01" & date <= "2021-04-05"),
    new2 = ifelse(date >= "2021-04-06" & date <= "2021-04-15", max(cmsm), rad))
```

Result:

```
         date rad new1 cmsm new2
1  2021-03-21   2   NA    0    2
2  2021-03-22   7   NA    0    7
3  2021-03-23   8   NA    0    8
4  2021-03-24  10   NA    0   10
5  2021-03-25   3   NA    0    3
6  2021-03-26   9   NA    0    9
7  2021-03-27   8   NA    0    8
8  2021-03-28   7   NA    0    7
9  2021-03-29   8   NA    0    8
10 2021-03-30   5   NA    0    5
11 2021-03-31   1   NA    0    1
12 2021-04-01   8   42    1    8
13 2021-04-02   9   42    2    9
14 2021-04-03   6   42    3    6
15 2021-04-04   9   42    4    9
16 2021-04-05   2   42    5    2
17 2021-04-06   2   NA    5    5
18 2021-04-07   7   NA    5    5
19 2021-04-08   9   NA    5    5
20 2021-04-09   8   NA    5    5
21 2021-04-10   4   NA    5    5
22 2021-04-11   3   NA    5    5
23 2021-04-12   4   NA    5    5
24 2021-04-13   9   NA    5    5
25 2021-04-14   9   NA    5    5
26 2021-04-15   4   NA    5    5
27 2021-04-16   6   NA    5    6
28 2021-04-17   5   NA    5    5
29 2021-04-18   9   NA    5    9
30 2021-04-19   3   NA    5    3
31 2021-04-20   8   NA    5    8
32 2021-04-21   3   NA    5    3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is not the desired output, however,  I am sure that I could not express what I want precisely. I adapted your code to meet my expectations. This is what I am looking for for the first question: `data$rad[data$date >= "2021-04-01" & data$date <= "2021-04-05"] <- 42` or  with dplyr :
`data %>%
  mutate(rad = ifelse(date >= "2021-04-01" & date <= "2021-04-05", 42, rad))`. I don't need the NA's, I need the original data on other dates. However, I would like to keep the original column and transfer the new output  onto a new column.

Comment: Then just create a new column: `data %>%   mutate(new = ifelse(date >= "2021-04-01" & date <= "2021-04-05", 42, rad))`

Comment: Regarding the second question, the desired output is as achieved by Waldi. I tried to adapt your code and had only partial success:
`data %>%
  mutate(cmsm = cumsum(date >= "2021-04-01" & date <= "2021-04-05")) %>%
  mutate(cmsm = ifelse(date > "2021-04-15" | date <"2021-04-01", rad, cmsm))`. The only difference is that the cumulative sum should calculate the rad values between 2021-04-01 - 2021-04-05 as following: 4,13,18,22, 32 and the full sum (32) should be transfered for 2021-04-06 - 2021-04-15

Comment: Have you seen my update? Does it do what you need?

Comment: At your first answer: Thank you very much, that was easy
At your second answer: First of all, "new1" is not needed. As I said in the question above, my first and second question are unrelated, I just use the same dataset as an example. Secondly, no, it is not what I am looking for. If I use your example I need a column like "new2" but the it should take the cumulative sum of rad between 2021-04-01 - 2021-04-05 as following: 8, 17 (8+9), 23 (17+6), 32 (23+9), 34 (32+2). Then from 2021-04-06 until 2021-04-15 it should take the value of the full cumulative sum of these five days: in this case 34